# Everytime i save my binary file it duplicates the info C#

Tags: c#

Everytime i save my binary file, it duplicates the content that is inside of my combobox.

I start with this:
[image: Start]
[image: Updated]

This is how i save in binary file:

```
try
        {
            // Escreve para ficheiro os empregados da empresa.
            FileStream ficheiro = new FileStream("BinaryFile.dat", FileMode.Create);
            //BinaryWriter fich = new BinaryWriter(ficheiro);
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ficheiro, ListasFilas.ListaMedico);
            //bf.Serialize(ficheiro, ListasFilas.ListaTecnicosAtendimento);
            //bf.Serialize(ficheiro, ListasFilas.ListaUrgencias);
            //bf.Serialize(ficheiro, ListasFilas.ListaUtentes);
            //bf.Serialize(ficheiro, ListasFilas.FilaAtAmarelo);
            //bf.Serialize(ficheiro, ListasFilas.FilaAtendimento);
            //bf.Serialize(ficheiro, ListasFilas.FilaAtRoxo);
            //bf.Serialize(ficheiro, ListasFilas.FilaAtVerde);
            //bf.Serialize(ficheiro, ListasFilas.FilaAtVermelho);

            ficheiro.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(err.StackTrace);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Guardado");
```

And this is how i load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            // Carregar dados
            FileStream ficheiro = File.Open("BinaryFile.dat", FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            ListasFilas.ListaMedico = (List<Medico>)bf.Deserialize(ficheiro);

            ficheiro.Close();

            // Criação de Médicos
            Medico Medico1 = new Medico("Oftalmologia");
            Medico1.NumFuncionario = 1;
            Medico1.Nome = "Razvan Almeida";
            Medico1.Telefone = 911506099;
            Medico1.Email = "razvan.slb@saude.com";
            ListasFilas.ListaMedico.Add(Medico1);
```

....

What it could be? Thank you!

Comment: Are you loading it after saving and not clearing the control/list first? Debug all the points where it loads or adds things to the list and see why.

Answer (score 0):

1. After button click (save button) reinitialize the value of combo box by assigning the null value to the data source property of combo box
2. Re-Populate the data source property of combo box with the new values